# PDF to XML Tablular data Extraction

Tags: xml, pdf

i want to extract tablular data from the PDF file,
i am using  Itext but i dont get the idea how to search the dablur data,(spliting)
Can any one give the idea related to search the table content.Here data is in unordered format,How to convert that data into understandable format.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include the data you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Get the page content and scan for MoveTo(x,y) (`tm`) and text (`tj`) commands.
Also a font change (`tf`), like marking a word bold, might split text.

```
        final String NUM = "\\d*\\.?\\d+";
        Pattern tj = Pattern.compile(".*\\((.*)\\) Tj");
        Pattern tm = Pattern.compile("\\d+ \\d+ \\d+ \\d+ ("
            + NUM + ") (" + NUM + ") Tm");
        Pattern tf = Pattern.compile("/(F\\d+) (" + NUM + ") Tf");

        byte[] pageContent = pdfReader.getPageContent(pageno);
        String pc = new String(pageContent, "Cp1252");
        try (BufferedReader pin = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(pc))) {
            for (;;) {
                String cline = pin.readLine();
                if (cline == null) {
                    break;
                }
                Matcher m = tm.matcher(cline);
                if (m.matches()) {
```

Mind that a fraction part (.123) might not alway be present, so a simple `Double.parseDouble(m.group(1))` does not suffice.

---

***How this works***

Above in the "page contens" you get lines of PostScript commands creating the page:
select a font, move to (x, y), print some characters.

*As an aside: the commands are in the so-called postfix notation: `100.0 200.0 Tm` (move-to x: 100, y: 200). First parameters, then command. For a stack-machine processing all. Hence the name "PostScript."*

If you get two move-to commands with same y, then you are on the same line.
Either another font is selected, for instance a word is made bold, or you are in a table.

You can imagine, that analizing a PDF makes for an interesting programming endeavour. I already envy you.

---

Java 7:

```
    try (BufferedReader pin = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(pc))) {
        ...
    }
```

Java 6:

```
    BufferedReader pin = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(pc));
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
       pin.close();
    }
```

Comment: Dear joop Eggen,i am new tp pdf.Actually i am reading pdf file data to text file format,But i want to split the data where table information is found.

Comment: Dear joop,Thanks for quick reply.I am trying to run the above code,but not successed.Can you give the detailed example(from where i take the PDF file) and related links,i am new to java and pdf ,sorry for my english.

Comment: I am really sorry, but that goes beyond my free moments for StackOverflow; maybe one source of errors might be that I already wrote for Java 7. I have added the Java 6 syntax. I used com.lowagie.itext 4.3.1, java.util.regex.Pattern, java.io.*. When you get the code running, you can simply start dumping.

Comment: Dear joop,is there any possibility to convert pdf to xml via apache tika.

Comment: Apache tika might well be the solution, though I am unfamiliar with it. Give it a try. As PDF is not structured content, but a list of output commands, the quality of tika PDF analysis depends on the effort put into it. Thanks.